Postfix mail server
I have installed the Postfix mail server. I am unable to send emails to Gmail, but it works for ProtonMail. Furthermore, I have also installed SMTP TLS to resolve the issue, but it hasn't made any difference.

Gmail has perhaps the toughest spam filter among all known email services. Make sure that you have configured all options:

MX record
DKIM Signature
SPF record
The absence of server's IP in SPAM databases

Not sure if this is a complete list, but in my case it was enough (didn't test it on Gmail).
